# Can I stack Super-Strength?

Tags: stacking, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

I know M&M 2e is out of print, but it's the game I collected and I recently opened some books up to make some new characters for a game.

Can I stack Super-Strength? My example is as follows:

I have a character who is strong, but I'd also like her to fly. Due to point costs, I can't have both at the ranks I'd like. A simple solution, of course, is just to make one an AP of the other. However, the drawback is that she can't fly and carry something too heavy at the same time.

Right now, with Enhanced Strength, her effective STR is 30, with a heavy load of 1,600 lbs. If I gave her 2 ranks in Super-Strength, that would up her effective STR to 40, with a heavy load of 3 tons (a medium load of 2 tons). So, with that medium load limit, she could lift and fly a sedan (at 2/3 normal speed).

So suppose I then created a separate power of Super-Strength of 6 with two Feats, costing 14 pp, and the AP of Flight 7, for a total cost of 15 pp. If I were switched to the Super-Strength 6, would that stack with the 2 other Super-Strength ranks so she would have 8 ranks in Super-Strength? And then, if she switched to Flight 7, she'd still have the 2 ranks of Super-Strength that is outside of the Super-Strength/Flight array?

Would that work? It's not breaking any PL limits, but just a way to maximize points to allow her to fly and carry *some* weight, or be on the ground and lift **lot** of weight.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. You need not apologize nor feel odd about asking questions about older games. The site is happy to field tabletop RPG questions, no matter the RPG's age. After all, every RPG is at least one person's all-time favorite RPG. Anyway, good luck with answers to your question, thank you for participating, and have fun.

Comment: In Mutants and Masterminds 3e this would be a Dynamic Alternate Power.

Comment: @nick012000: ^_^ Surely you mean "Alternate Effect". "Alternate Power" is the 2E version. And yes, 2E allowed for Dynamic APs (as well as a few other variants such as Wide Arrays, and the mentioned Power Reserve).

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in the rules preventing ranks from stacking (with GM approval, of course). The Hero Lab software, which was vetted by Green Ronin for their system, supports a +0 "Stacking" modifier to allow these values to sum up, and I'm pretty sure there were official builds that used this setup.

Lastly, the *Ultimate Power* supplement (which, admittedly, is not primary canon according to Steve Kenson, although he did intend it to be the corrected powers for 2E) has a Power Reserve power that essentially operates as a Dynamic Array that *only* allows you to add to existing powers.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. As for Ultimate Power, I was thumbing through it and didn't see "Power Battery" but did see "Power Reserve" which sounds like what you were talking about-- all very helpful. Thanks for your quick reply!!

Comment: @Cuneiformist: If this answers your question, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].